# Can there be mapping between two ElasticSearch indexes?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

*This is kind of a noob question so please be kind.*

I have an elasticsearch cluster (v5) with 3 nodes and two indexes, lets say indexes X and Y(default). I would like to know if there is a way to write data to the index X and automatically write data to index Y. Is there something built in to ES, for doinf so?

I have read about ES mappings, however I am not sure I understand the concept and if this is the way to go.

I have read about watches and triggers, but I think they are only available in paid versions.

Comment: How are you ingesting data? You would need to ingest the data in both index at same time.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I do not have anything in particular set up for ingesting. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: By ingesting I mean how are you sending data to elasticsearch? There is no automatically way to do what you want, you need to write in both index at the same time.

Comment: I am creating a client for the ES cluster and posting data to one index. I have seen an example where somehow ( in a similar case) the second index was filling up with data without an apparent action being taken, and when I read about mappings, I thought they could do the job. Now you say there is no way for it to be done automatically, so maybe I am missing somthing on the example I am looking for. Maybe some other service or something.

Comment: Mappings are used to define the data type of your fields, it is configured per index or used on index templates. To write the same date on multiple index you need to do that when indexing, so in your client you will need to have a logic that you send the request to elasticsearch to write on multiple index.

Answer (score 0):

Thier is a way but it is present in X-PACK
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest-enriching-data.html

You can always build your own ingestPipeline as stated by @leandrojmp using say kafka kind of thing where you will push the payload that you want to presist in another index Y.